# jquery DataTables: single Object json to rows with key as column1 and value as col2

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**REF:** https://datatables.net/

Is it possible with data-tables to convert a single object json returned from server to rows of a table with key being column1 and value as column2.

**Single Object Json from server:**

```
{"data":"abc","name":"Diago","Age":23}
```

**Sample Table:** 
generated with above json with key:value pair as row

```
----------------------
| key    |    value  |
----------------------
| data   |   abc     |
| name   |   Diago   |
| Age    |   23      |
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this code:

```
$(function() {
  json = '[{"data":"abc","name":"Diago","Age":23}]';

  parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
  var otable = $("#datatable").dataTable();
  otable.fnClearTable();
  $.each(parsedJson[0], function(key, value) {
    otable.dataTable().fnAddData([
      key,
      value
    ]);
  })
});
```

[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kVMprP8BZ6aik2DRjh7D?p=preview)

Hope this helps

Comment: I did similar as i found I cant do it inside Otable as we do manipulate columns.

Answer (score 1):

You will love this:

https://igniteui.com/grid/overview

Standard solution:

```
var json = {"data":"abc","name":"Diago","Age":23};
var output = [];
output.push("<table>");
$.each(json, function(k, v) {
            output.push("<tr><td>");
            output.push(k);
            output.push("</td><td>");
            output.push(v);    
            output.push("</td></tr>");
});
output.push("</table>");

console.log(output.join(""));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NbvH9/)

**FULL SOLUTION TO YOUR QUESTION:**

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  var json = {"data":"abc","name":"Diago","Age":23};
  var output = [];
  output.push("<table>");
  $.each(json, function(k, v) {
            output.push("<tr><td>");
            output.push(k);
            output.push("</td><td>");
            output.push(v);    
            output.push("</td></tr>");
  });
  output.push("</table>");

  $("#container").append(output.join(""));

  $("#container").find("table").dataTable();


});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I get what you are suggesting but I need native datatables solution like aoColumn options et. when provided ajax url.

Comment: so put those settings in `.dataTable()`